# How do i create a cms static block showing image and text (inline or beside it) with a link to a product or category

Tags: static-block

How do i create a cms static block showing image and text (inline or beside it) with a link to a product or category just like the luma static block on home page. I tried to edit the text on the luma home-page-block, After saving it the default text keeps showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create CMS static block with your content and call in CMS page content using below code.

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="yourblockid"}}
```

Comment: If above answer helps to  you please vote so someone use same